# How to visually print letters in the console in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

I have an assignment for my C# course. This is a basic introductory code so the tasks are not that complex, but this one task I'm not sure how to solve.
See the attached image: [Assignment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzz98.png)

The goal of this first assignment is to learn about variables and operators, so I am not expecting it to be that complex of a solution.

Thankful for a respone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's like a thousand ways you could do that. If you are feeling fancy you could have a two dimensional array with zeros and ones (or true and false) that would describe the letters, and then write a function to loop over it printing whitespace if it encounters a zero/false and the letter when it encounters one/true. Or you could just have the exact string value of the letter saved in a variable and just print it as-is. Anyways there's not much more to that task than printing letters, whitespaces and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I guess this does the trick, although its not the nicest code

```
   public static void Task4()
        {
            //Task 4.
            Console.WriteLine("Task 4");
            Console.WriteLine(" OOOOOOO " +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\nO\tO" +
                "\n OOOOOOO \n");
            Console.WriteLine("BBBBBBBB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nBBBBBBBB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nB\tB" +
                "\nBBBBBBBB");
        }
```